# permission denied using subprocess in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

```
import subprocess

ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-o', 'BatchMode=yes', <myhostname>], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print ssh.stderr.readlines()
```

When I run the code above I get the error **"Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n"**

Most of the similar questions I've read are using linux, but I am using windows. I've also used paramiko and didn't have this permission issue, but I need to use subprocess to try something different that I can't do with paramiko.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what is it you can't do with paramiko? (On Linux, you'd want to take out the `shell=True` to fix this, but on Windows I'm not much help on that end of the problem; that said, I'm fairly familiar with both paramiko and OpenSSH, and quite curious what functionality you're looking for but can't find).

Comment: It appears the error is coming from `ssh` itself and not from Python, correct? That implies an error in the parameters supplied to `ssh`. Maybe something missing?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but basically I'm using paramiko to configure a switch remotely. Whenever I add a vlan (and ports to the vlan) to this switch, it automatically gets disabled even though the settings on the switch are to enable the ports. If I run the same commands locally on the switch, everything is fine. I'm not sure if it's the interface between my python script and the switch. This is why I'm now trying to use subprocess to see if it's paramiko that's causing the issue.